# How to make multiple select boxes dynamic in using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having multiple select boxes with multiple options, on click of select box row is going to add and remove how to do for multiple select boxes in `ReactJS`

```
this.state = {
    checked: false ,
    rows: [],
    rows2: [],
    selectedOption: null
  };
  this.CheckBox = this.CheckBox.bind(this);
handleChangeSelect = selectedOption => {

    const item = {
        name: "",
        qty: "",
        uom: "",
      };

    if(!selectedOption || selectedOption.length==0){
        //None of the option is selected
        this.setState({
            rows2: this.state.rows2.slice(0,0)
          }); 

    }else if(selectedOption.length < this.state.rows2.length){
       //One option is removed
       this.setState({
        rows2: this.state.rows2.slice(0, -1)
      }); 

    }
    else{
        //One option selected
        this.setState({
            rows2: [...this.state.rows2, item]
        });
    }


    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  CheckBox() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    })
  } 


  handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      name: "",
      qty: "",
      uom: "",





    };


    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRowSelect = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows2: this.state.rows2.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    <input type="text" name="attribute" /> 

 }
```

Comment: Avoid asking the same question multiple times, try to edit the previous one is preferred.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make multiple select box dynamic in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965437/how-to-make-multiple-select-box-dynamic-in-reactjs)